# Whitebox Tools QGIS Plugin for Mac can't be verified

Tags: qgis, mac, whitebox-tools

I'm trying to get Whitebox Tools in QGIS (3.18.2 Zurich) working. It seems to have installed and linked up to the executable file fine. However, I can't get my system to run the .exe file (Mac Big Sur 11.2.3). Normally, you can override issues like this from Privacy and Settings, but the option doesn't appear after I get the error message. See attached.

Has anyone found their way around this before?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually resolved this:

Just had to run the executable file outside of QGIS by simply clicking on it. The option to override then became available in Privacy and Settings.